# use product of select BBDD with the CRUD of backpack

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

[image]

Hello,
we have acquired backpack laravel for a specific project. We have established communication with an additional database, from which we obtain the result of a SELECT, the result we want to show with the CRUD view for filtering or exporting the data

Comment: **Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.** please check **[Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

that controller is not extending the CrudController. You are not using any Backpack function there. Please refeer to backpack documentation here: https://backpackforlaravel.com/ have a look on the quick start.

Cheers